# File Permissions on recovered folders

Tags: permissions, data-recovery

I have had to recover an Ubuntu Clonezilla machine. The computer died, harddrive intact. New computer, not same model so I have transferred the folders to the *public* profile. I have rebuilt the machine and have Clonezilla operational, however, I am unable to move the files into the folder tree of Clonezilla to access the files...

1: the files are owned by *root* and *sudo* will not move them.

2: it tells me access is denied.

How can I change the file ownership and access to be able to move these files to the correct file path for Clonezilla to access?

Thank you

---

Output of `ls -la`

```
total 120
drwxr-xr-x 19 guy  guy  4096 Jan 11 16:49 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Jan 10 13:01 ..
-rw-------  1 guy  guy  1746 Jan 11 10:16 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 guy  guy   220 Dec 27 10:00.bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 guy  guy  3771 Dec 27 10:00 .bashrc
drwx------ 17 guy  guy  4096 Jan  7 11:33 .cache
drwx------  3 guy  guy  4096 Jan  7 14:18 .compiz
drwx------ 15 guy  guy  4096 Jan 10 13:06 .config
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Dec 27 12:09 .dbus
drwxr-xr-x  2 guy  guy  4096 Jan 11 10:17 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  2 guy  guy  4096 Jan 10 12:43 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  3 guy  guy  4096 Dec 27 10:15 Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1 guy  guy  8980 Dec 27 10:00 examples.desktop
drwx------  3 guy  guy  4096 Jan 11 09:07 .gconf
-rw-r-----  1 guy  guy     0 Dec 27 13:44 .gksu.lock
drwx------  3 guy  guy  4096 Jan 10 13:30 .gnupg
-rw-------  1 guy  guy  2282 Jan 10 13:30 .ICEauthority
drwx------  3 guy  guy  4096 Dec 27 10:07 .local
drwx------  5 guy  guy  4096 Dec 27 10:14 .mozilla
drwxr-xr-x  2 guy  guy  4096 Dec 27 10:07 Music
-rw-rw-r--  1 guy  guy     0 Jan 11 16:49 permissions.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 guy  guy  4096 Dec 27 10:07 Pictures
-rw-r--r--  1 guy  guy   655 Dec 27 10:00 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  3 guy  guy  4096 Dec 27 12:20 Public
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jan 10 12:53 public
-rw-r--r--  1 guy  guy     0 Dec 27 10:18 .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwxr-xr-x  2 guy  guy  4096 Dec 27 10:07 Templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 guy  guy  4096 Dec 27 10:07 Videos
-rw-------  1 guy  guy    53 Jan 10 13:30 .Xauthority
-rw-------  1 guy  guy    82 Jan 10 13:30 .xsession-errors
-rw-------  1 guy  guy  1177 Jan 10 13:20 .xsession-errors.old
```

Comment: can you please post the output of `ls -la`?

Comment: Thanks Boba Fit, is there a way to create a txt file output to post?..I apologise, I do not know how to post onto this forum or how to from Ubuntu.. Im learning. :)

Comment: after a comand you can put `> textfile.txt`. The Output will be directet and write (overwrite) the textfile.txt (you may change the name)

Comment: Best way I could do it.. hope thats ok.. thanks Boba Fit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the owner of a folder by `sudo chown guy:guy .`

If you want to change the owner also in every subfolder and every file, you may add `-R`

So I recommend you to use `sudo chown guy:guy . -R`

Comment: Boba Fit!!  Thank you so much.. that command helped me to take ownership from root, move the folder to my choice and Clonezilla runs from my restored images now!! The Force is Strong in you!

Comment: Now you can follow this Guidline: https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers to see what you can do, after you get a good answer.